# How does GitHub produce this diff?

Tags: git, github, diff

Here's the diff in question. It's a view of 2/3 commits for a Pull Request:
https://github.com/codeapprove/meta/pull/15/files/5b7549cd97845c41019478f8f339a90c0256014f..7327dfcfb3a95b31f8bf4845556196abe33fefc8

GitHub shows the diff like this:
[image: GitHub diff]

However if I do a naive `git diff` at the command line I get something else:

```
git diff 5b7549cd97845c41019478f8f339a90c0256014f..7327dfcfb3a95b31f8bf4845556196abe33fefc8
diff --git a/index.js b/index.js
index 5f87902..1885a31 100644
--- a/index.js
+++ b/index.js
@@ -5,6 +5,10 @@ function main(args) {
   console.info(args);
 }

+function qooBoz() {
+  console.log("qooBoz");
+}
+
 function fooBar(x, y) {
   const z = x + y;
   return z;
@@ -16,6 +20,7 @@ function barBaz(q, z) {
 }

 function bizBom(a, b) {
+  console.log("bizBom");
   const c = a + b;
   return c;
 }
```

The difference is that GitHub seems to be "ignoring" the merge commit and just focusing on the changes made by the PR author. In most cases that's the relevant diff and what I'd ike to see.

How can I get that same diff at the command line, knowing only the two commit hashes `5b7549cd97845c41019478f8f339a90c0256014f` and `7327dfcfb3a95b31f8bf4845556196abe33fefc8`?

**Edit 1**

I think a clearer way to ask is: what is the difference between what GitHub is doing, in terms of git operations, at these two links:

https://github.com/codeapprove/meta/pull/15/files/5b7549cd97845c41019478f8f339a90c0256014f..7327dfcfb3a95b31f8bf4845556196abe33fefc8

[image: GitHub diff]

https://github.com/codeapprove/meta/compare/5b7549cd97845c41019478f8f339a90c0256014f..7327dfcfb3a95b31f8bf4845556196abe33fefc8

[image: GitHub diff]

Comment: Three dots vs two dots?

Comment: Please post a diagram of the relevant commits in tree form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This becomes much clearer when you look at the graph:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline
* 7327dfc (HEAD -> add-biz-bom, origin/add-biz- bom) Add logging
*   fab1ea5 Merge branch 'main' into add-biz-bom
|\
| * 0d8e5b1 (origin/main, origin/HEAD, main) Add qooBoz function
* | 5b7549c Add bizBom function
|/
* 2e178d9 Add more to index.js
* a9fdc92 Update index.js
...
```

The reason GitHub is "ignoring" the merge commit (`fab1ea5`) is because:

1. The merge commit itself has no changes (this is typical).
2. The commit that the merge brings in is `0d8e5b1` which is already in `main`, so from the point of view of this PR that commit will not be added to `main` when the PR is completed.

The view you linked to is only diffing **2 commits**; one is the merge commit with no changes, and the other is commit `7327dfcf` which by itself just adds the one line console log you see in the screenshot. If you want to see that from the command line you could use:

`git diff fab1ea5..7327dfc`

or if you didn't "know" what the commit ID of the merge commit was, you could use:

`git diff 7327dfc~1..7327dfc`

**Side Note**: If you're interested in seeing the diff for all 3 commits *in the context of this PR*, to mimic that set of changes you could use:

`git diff 0d8e5b1...7327dfc`

or perhaps more intuitively:

`git diff origin/main...origin/add-biz-bom`

Note for most of the above commands you could use either 2 dots (..) or 3 dots (...) and you'd get the same answer in this case. But for the last one using the branch names in the context of a PR, you should always use 3 dots, since `origin/main` could be ahead of the merge-base of your PR. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69559520/184546) for a quick cheat sheet on the differences between 2 and 3 dots.

**Caveat:** Even the last diff command of the two branches is an over-simplification. If some changes were added to both the source and target branches of a PR (say, due to cherry-picking or duplicated efforts by different people), then the actual diff *in the context of the PR* could be a subset of the output of that last command.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I am probably just being dense but I still don't quite get what's going on here. I have edited my answer to present my confusion a bit more concisely.

I like your working of _in the context of the PR_. It seems that GitHub shows one kind of diff in context and another kind if I just ask for a pure commit comparison.

Comment: @SamStern regarding your edit, this is actually covered in the answer already, but I see where the confusion lies. Obviously the second screenshot is an exact diff from the command line: `git diff 5b7549c..7327dfc`. The answer for the first one is trickier, because it "is in the context of the PR". The answer I gave for that one is not exactly what GitHub is doing behind the scenes, but the result is equivalent to: `git diff fab1ea5..7327dfc`. The reason for that is it has to subtract out what's already on `main`. (cont...)

Comment: So, take this diff: `git diff 5b7549c..7327dfc` and combine it with this diff: `git diff origin/main..2e178d9`. The result of combining those yields just the changes in the top commit, which is the diff of the merge commit and top commit.

Comment: Perhaps a different wording will help. Your PR has 3 commits not on `main`. 1 of those commits is just a merge commit with no changes, so there are only 2 commits in your PR with changes in them. If you view changes for all 3 commits, you see the new bizBom function get added with the console log line. But if you view changes for just the top 2 commits as you did, the only change there is adding the console log line. Don't get thrown off by the URL syntax: the compare URL is a diff of the 2 commits, the pull request syntax is doing multiple diffs behind the scenes and putting them together.

Comment: Thank you for all the extra info!

Comment: @SamStern Just FYI, the last sentence of my previous comment may be a little misleading. I don't know for sure how GitHub calculates what to show for a PR diff; it's possible GitHub actually does a temporary merge and uses that temporary merge commit behind the scenes to show the diff in the context of a PR. I think "what a PR shows" has changed over time too. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48570464/184546) for more details.